# Turn off receiving emails from main iCloud email address?

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, gmail

I would like to use an iCloud email alias instead of my main iCloud email address because the main one does a terrible job at filtering spam messages. I also can't stand the email address name that I created back when I first created the account. Is there a way to do this? Trying to reduce the amount of emails that I have and move over from Gmail.

Comment: You can use any email service that allows forwarding the mail to your iCloud address.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible.

From [Add and manage email aliases for iCloud Mail on iCloud.com](https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/add-and-manage-email-aliases-mm6b1a490a/icloud):

> Note: You can’t delete or turn off a primary iCloud Mail address. You can’t use an alias to create a separate Apple ID, and an email alias can’t be converted to a primary iCloud Mail address.

Answer (score 1):

On iCloud.com you can set some basic rules for incoming email to delete any emails to your primary Apple ID.

Open iCloud.com and navigate to Mail. Click the cogwheel in the upper-left and choose Preferences. Select Rules > Add rule.

Use the "is addressed to" option and put in the email you want to block. Choose an action, likely "Move to trash."

---

Remember that any email, even those from Apple, addressed to your mail address will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

for those looking for answers here, the "main" email address is your iCloud account, aliases of that account can be deactivated (*iCloud allows you to make alternates to use which just point to your inbox) but since the main email is your account its not possible to turn that one off.

Answer (score -3):

You can create an alias for your iCloud mail by going to Mail on iCloud.com.  Tap the settings button at the top of the mailboxes list.  [Here’s a link from Apple.](https://support.apple.com/guide/icloud/add-and-manage-email-aliases-mm6b1a490a/icloud)

If you have iCloud+ you also have the option of using a custom domain.

Comment: That doesn’t answer my question, I know how to create an email alias in iCloud. I want to know if there’s a way I can “turn off” the main iCloud email address and use the alias as my main instead. I don’t want to receive new emails from the main address.

Comment: I suppose you could simply change your "main" email address for iCloud to the proposed alias, and then add the old "main" one back as an alias for the new one.  But why not just stop looking at the "main" one, and only look at the alias?  You do not need to forward the alias to the main address, and you could also use different mail clients for each.  Would that not work for your purposes?